# Yii2 2amigos/yii2-tinymce-widget Modal

Tags: yii2, tinymce

I am trying to implement the 2amigos/yii2-tinymce-widget into a modal popup.  It works the first time it is opened, but then the next call the TinyMCE does not display.

I've found a couple posts on the subject

https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-tinymce-widget/issues/24
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/549

but I can't seem to get it to work.

Can anyone help me get this sorted out.

In my index view is

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\bootstrap\Modal; //used to make create a popup window
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel backend\models\TicketsSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Tickets');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="tickets-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <p>
        <?php // = Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Create Tickets'), ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
        <?= Html::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> '.Yii::t('app', 'New Ticket'), 
            [
                'id'=>'modalCreateButton',
                'class' => 'btn btn-success modalButton',
                'value'=>Url::to('index.php?r=tickets/create'), 
                'title'=>Yii::t('app', 'New Ticket'), 
            ]) 
        ?>
    </p>
<?php Pjax::begin(['id'=>'ticketsListGrid']); ?>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'id' => 'grid',
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'TicketId',
            'ProjectId',
            'TicketDate',
            'Description',
            'TicketStatusId',
            'TicketSeverityId',
            'UserId',
            //'dtCreated',
            //'dtModified',

            // ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
            [   
                'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                'template' => '{update} {delete}',
                'buttons'=>[
                    'update' => function($url,$model,$key){
                        $btn =  Html::a(
                                    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>',
                                    Url::to('index.php?r=tickets/update').'&id='.$key,
                                    [
                                        'id' => 'modalUpdateButton',
                                        'class' => 'grid-action modalButton', 
                                        'value'=>Url::to('index.php?r=tickets/update').'&id='.$key, 
                                        'title'=>Yii::t('app', 'Updating Ticket: ').$model->TicketId,
                                    ]
                                );
                        return $btn;
                    }
                ]
            ],
        ],
    ]); ?>
    <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
</div>
<?php
    //Modal Popup
    Modal::begin([
        'id'=>'modal',
        'class'=>'modal',
        'size'=>'modal-lg', //modal-sm or modal-lg
        'headerOptions' => ['id' => 'modalHeader'],
        'header' => '<span id="modalHeaderTitle"></span>',
        'closeButton' => [
            'label'=>'Close',
            'id'=>'close-button',
            'class'=>'btn btn-warning pull-right modalClose',
        ],
        'clientOptions' => [
            'backdrop' => 'static', // true,
            'keyboard' => false, // true,
        ]
    ]);
    echo '<div id="message"></div>';
    echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";
    Modal::end();
?>
<?php 
    $this->registerJs('$("#modal").on("shown.bs.modal",function(){
        alert("");
        tinymce.init({
            "branding":false,
            "plugins":["advlist autolink lists link charmap print preview anchor","searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen","insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste","textcolor"],
            "toolbar":"undo redo | styleselect forecolor backcolor | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
            "selector":"#tickets-details"
        });
    });', yii\web\View::POS_READY);
?>
```

I use the following JS for my modal

```
$(document).on('ready pjax:success', function() {
    $('.modalButton').click(function () {
        $('#modal').modal('show')
            .find('#modalContent')
            .load($(this).attr('value'));
        document.getElementById('modalHeaderTitle').innerHTML = '<h4>' + $(this).attr('title') + '</h4>';
        return false; //Stop default link reloading of page
    });
});
$('.modalButton').click(function () {
    $('#modal').modal('show')
        .find('#modalContent')
        .load($(this).attr('value'));
    document.getElementById('modalHeaderTitle').innerHTML = '<h4>' + $(this).attr('title') + '</h4>';

    return false; //Stop default link reloading of page
});
```

and then my _form for the modal is

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
// use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm; //used to enable bootstrap layout options.
use yii\widgets\Pjax;

use yii\helpers\Url; //used to make create a popup window
use yii\bootstrap\Modal; //used to make create a popup window

use kartik\widgets\DatePicker;
use dosamigos\tinymce\TinyMce;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model backend\models\Tickets */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="tickets-form">

    <?php 
        $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id'=>$model->formName(),
        'layout' => 'horizontal', //'default', 'horizontal' or 'inline'
        'class' => 'form-horizontal',
        'fieldConfig' => [
            'enableError' => true,
            'options'=>['class'=>'']
        ]
    ]); 
    ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php
        echo $form->field(
            $model, 
            'UserId',
            [ 'template' => '<div class="col-sm-2">{label}</div><div class="col-sm-3">{input}{error}</div>' , ]
        )->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label ( null , [ 'class' => 'control-label' ] );
    ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <?php
        echo $form->field(
            $model, 
            'ProjectId',
            [ 'template' => '<div class="col-sm-2">{label}</div><div class="col-sm-7">{input}{error}</div>' , ]
        )->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label ( null , [ 'class' => 'control-label' ] );
    ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <?php
        echo $form->field(
            $model, 
            'TicketDate',
            [ 'template' => '<div class="col-sm-2">{label}</div><div class="col-sm-4">{input}{error}</div>' , ]
        )->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label ( null , [ 'class' => 'control-label' ] );
    ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <?php
        echo $form->field(
            $model, 
            'Description',
            [ 'template' => '<div class="col-sm-2">{label}</div><div class="col-sm-10">{input}{error}</div>' , ]
        )->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label ( null , [ 'class' => 'control-label' ] );
    ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <?php
        // echo $form->field(
        //     $model, 
        //     'Details',
        //     [ 'template' => '<div class="col-sm-2">{label}</div><div class="col-sm-10">{input}{error}</div>' , ]
        // )->textArea(['rows' => 12])->label ( null , [ 'class' => 'control-label' ] );
        echo $form->field(
                $model, 
                'Details',
                [ 'template' => '<div class="col-sm-2">{label}</div><div class="col-sm-10">{input}{error}</div>' , ]
            )->widget(TinyMce::className(), [
                'options' => ['rows' => 12],
                'language' => 'en',
                'clientOptions' => [
                    'plugins' => [
                        "advlist autolink lists link charmap print preview anchor",
                        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
                        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste",
                        "textcolor"
                    ],
                    'toolbar' => "undo redo | styleselect forecolor backcolor | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
                ]
            ]);
?>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <?php
        echo $form->field(
            $model, 
            'TicketStatusId',
            [ 'template' => '<div class="col-sm-2">{label}</div><div class="col-sm-4">{input}{error}</div>' , ]
        )->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label ( null , [ 'class' => 'control-label' ] );
    ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <?php
        echo $form->field(
            $model, 
            'TicketSeverityId',
            [ 'template' => '<div class="col-sm-2">{label}</div><div class="col-sm-4">{input}{error}</div>' , ]
        )->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label ( null , [ 'class' => 'control-label' ] );
    ?>
</div>

<!--     <?= $form->field($model, 'UserId')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ProjectId')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'TicketDate')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'Description')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'TicketStatusId')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'TicketSeverityId')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'dtCreated')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'dtModified')->textInput() ?> -->

    <div class="row form-group">
        <?php // = Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Save'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
        <?php
//Form button(s)
    echo Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk' aria-hidden='true'></span> ".Yii::t('app', 'Create') : "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk' aria-hidden='true'></span> ".Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-block btn-success form-cmd' : 'btn btn-block btn-primary form-cmd'])
?>
    </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <?php
        Modal::begin([
            'id'=>'modalPopup',
            'class'=>'modalPopup',
            'size'=>'modal-lg',
            'headerOptions' => ['id' => 'modalPopupHeader'],
            'header' => '<span id="modalHeaderTitle"></span>',
            'closeButton' => [
                'label'=>'Close',
                'id'=>'closeButton',
                'class'=>'btn btn-warning pull-right',
            ],
            'clientOptions' => [
                'backdrop' => 'static', //true,
                'keyboard' => false, // true,
            ]
        ]);
        echo '<div id="message"></div>';
        echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";
        Modal::end();
    ?>
</div>
<?php 
$script = <<< JS
    $('form#{$model->formName()}').on('beforeSubmit', function(e){
        var \$form = $(this);
        $.post(
            \$form.attr("action"), //serialize Yii2 form 
            \$form.serialize()
        )

        .done(function(result){
            //console.log(result);
            result = JSON.parse(result);
            //alert(result + " " + result.message + " " + result.status);
            if(result.status == 'Success'){
                $(\$form).trigger("reset");
                $.pjax.reload({container:'#grid'}); //requery the main form's grid with the new addition
                $(document).find('#modal').modal('hide');
                $("#message").html(result.message);
            }else{
                $(\$form).trigger("reset");
                $("#message").html(result.message);
            }
        })

        .fail(function(){
            console.log("server error");
        });

        return false;
    });

    $(function(){
        $('.showModal').click(function (){
            // $('#modalCreate').modal('hide');
            $('#modalPopup').modal('show')
                .find('#modalContent')
                .load($(this).attr('value'));
                // document.getElementById('modalHeader').innerHTML = '<button type="button" id="close-button" class="btn btn-warning pull-right" data-dismiss="modalPopup" data-target="modalCreate" data-toggle="modalCreate" aria-hidden="true">Close</button><h4>' + $(this).attr('title') + '</h4>';
                // document.getElementById('modalHeader').innerHTML = '<button type="button" id="close-button" class="btn btn-warning pull-right" aria-hidden="true">Close</button><h4>' + $(this).attr('title') + '</h4>';
        });


    });
JS;
$this->registerJS($script);
?>
```

Comment: are you getting any errors in devtools?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined and the error is flagged in my $("#modal").on("shown.bs.modal",function(){ ... code

Answer (score 0):

Each time you close the modal you need to use the `remove()` API to get rid of TinyMCE.  If you don't do that then TinyMCE still thinks its tied to the old modal (which was destroyed) so it won't initialize again with the new modal.

Comment: But how?  I've tried several bit of code I've found but can't seem to implement any properly (I'm most probably the issue - a complete novice!)  Can you guide me a little bit more on properly implementing your concept?

Comment: I don't know anything about the Yii2 stuff so I really can't tell you how you would do this.  I would guess there is an event tied to the modal being removed - that is when you would want to do this.

Comment: I added a js that run tinymce.remove(); when the modal window is closed which does in fact make the tinymce appear, but now I have no content anymore.  Any ideas?  I tried running init() before showing the modal, but that had no effect.

Comment: You can't insert content into the editor until its initialized.  There is an event that will tell you when the editor is initialized:http://fiddle.tinymce.com/qigaab